# Generic FindElement method in Java

Tags: java, selenium

I wonder how to convert this 2 generic methods for `Selenium` in `C#` to `Java` version since I dont have any experience in `Java`:

```
public static IWebElement WaitAndFindElement(Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> expectedCondtions, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
    webDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
    return webDriverWait.Until(expectedCondtions);
}

public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> WaitAndFindElements(Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> expectedCondtions, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
    webDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
    return webDriverWait.Until(expectedCondtions);
}
```

Comment: Then you should start learning Java! What use are two methods if you do not have anything else in Java, do not understand the Java methods and do not know how to maintain them?

Answer (score 0):

1st one:
     // Wait for an element to become clickable

```
public static void WaitAndClick(WebElement elementToBeClicked) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elementToBeClicked));
        wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToBeClicked));

        elementToBeClicked.click();

    } catch (Exception e)

    {
        Logger_Info("Element not clicked yet. waiting some more for " + elementToBeClicked);

        if (waitCounter < 3) {
            waitCounter++;
            WaitAndClick(elementToBeClicked);
        }
        waitCounter = 0;
    }
```

2nd One:

```
// Wait for an element to become visible

public static void WaitUntilVisible(WebDriver driver, WebElement elementToBeClicked) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    try {


        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elementToBeClicked));
        if (!elementToBeClicked.isDisplayed()) {
            Logger_Info("Element not visible yet. waiting some more for " + elementToBeClicked);
            if (waitCounter < 3) {
                waitCounter++;
                WaitUntilVisible(elementToBeClicked);
            }
            waitCounter = 0;
        }

    } catch (Exception e)

    {
        Logger_Info("Handling exception");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about sent to the function the expected condtions that i want to use instead of using several method ? (clickable, visible, presence...)

Answer (score 0):

It's a very straight forward conversion: `Func` => `java.util.function.Function` `IWebDriver` => `WebDriver` (same for web element) `typeof` => `.class`. Altogether:

```
public static WebElement waitAndFindElement(Function<WebDriver, WebElement> expectedCondtions, int timeoutInSeconds) {
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    return webDriverWait.until(expectedCondtions);
}

public static List<WebElement> waitAndFindElements(Function<WebDriver, List<WebElement>> expectedCondtions, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(webDriverWait.until(expectedCondtions));
}
```